# Update Invoice Line Fields

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

All invoices for our customers are monthly subscriptions, based on current month quantities (every month the invoice is different). We have linked the monthly quantities from SalesForce to the NetSuite customer record, and I would like to have the invoices auto-update every month to the correct quantities.

We currently update the quantities via csv import. There is only one line item for each invoice, which I assumed would make this process relatively easy. I currently have the saved search, seen in the below code, bring over the quantity field so we can reimport.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/search', 'N/record', 'N/email', 'N/runtime'],
/**
 * 
 * @param {search} search 
 * @param {record} record 
 * @param {email} email 
 * @param {runtime} runtime 
 */
function(search, record, email, runtime) {
    function execute(context) {

        var searchid = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({'name': 'custscript_customsearch630'});

        search.load({'id': searchid}).run().each(function(result){
            var newQuantity = result.getValue({'name': 'custentitynumber_lives.customer'});
            var internalId = result.getValue({'name': 'internalid'});


        var invoice = record.load({'type': record.Type.INVOICE,'id': internalId,'isDynamic': true});
        var sublistId = 'item';

        invoice.selectLine({'sublistId': sublistId, 'line' : 1});
        invoice.setCurrentSublistValue({'sublistId': sublistId, 'fieldId':'quantity', 'value': newQuantity});
        invoice.commitLine({'sublistId': sublistId});

        invoice = invoice.save({'ignoreMandatoryFields': true})

        return true;

        });
    }

    return {
        'execute': execute
    };
});
```

I'm currently receiving the following error for this:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"Please choose an item to add","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)"
```

Comment: sublist indexes are 0-based in SS2. I think you want `line:0`.

Comment: @ehcanadian Thank you! That made progress, but now it set the Quantity Amounts to 1, compared to what the 'custentitynumber_lives' field on the customer record shows.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a join; `var newQuantity = result.getValue({'name': 'custentitynumber_lives', 'join': 'customer'});`

Comment: @ehcanadian THANK YOU! Works perfectly.